# How to apply icon over an image when images are fetching from an api

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, css-position

I have an api that fetches the images of dogs and I want to apply heart icon (like favourite feature) over it . When clicked , that image should also get display on the favourites section. I am not able to find to how to apply heart icon over the images.

```
<div className="container3">
      {
        imageUrls && imageUrls.map(record => {
          return (
            <>
            < div className="col-sm" >
              <img src={record} alt='i'></img>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} className='heart-icon' style={{color: "#ff0000",}} />
            </div>
            </>
          )

        })
      }
    </div>
```

Can anybody help me with the css

I am getting heart icon above the images and also not in same alignment. I want the heart icon to be at the bottom right of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting a `position: absolute` on the icon. Make sure the `img` is wrapped by a `div`, set the width and height you want on the `div` and then set the `img` to width and height of 100%. Make sure the icon is within the same `div` and set the position on the icon to absolute e.g `position: absolute`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I recomend using absolute positioning to achive this. Put your icon element as a child of the image element, then give the child this css:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```